# settings api - add_settings_section not working

Tags: plugin-development, settings-api

I'm building a plugin options page but I can't get the sections to appear.

This is my code:

ini.php:

```
class Setup {
    public function init() {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_my_plugin_menu' ) );
    }

    public function add_my_plugin_menu() {
        add_submenu_page( 'tools.php', 'My Plugin', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', 'my_plugin', array( $this, 'my_plugin_builder' ) );
    }

    public function my_plugin_builder() {
        require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/builder.php';
    }
}

if ( class_exists( 'Setup' ) ) {
    $setup = new Setup();
    $setup->init();
}
```

builder.php:

```
$my_plugin_sections = [
    'first_section' => [
        'title' => 'first section'
    ]
];

do_settings_sections( 'my_plugin' ); 

function my_plugin_init_settings() {
    global $my_plugin_sections;

    foreach ($my_plugin_sections as $id => $value) {
        add_settings_section( $id, $value['title'], 'my_plugin_callback', 'my_plugin');
    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'my_plugin_init_settings');

function my_plugin_callback() {return null;}
```

Why the 'first section' is not showing up? I deleted the extra code related to fields to minimize the problem, it still not showing up. Thank you.

Comment: The formatting of `$my_plugin_sections` looks odd. You may need to make a conventional PHP array instead of this JSON-looking notation.

Comment: @WebElaine It works with that array just fine in my theme, but my plugin is a different issue because I'm not storing the code in one file. Thanks but that shouldn't cause an issue, just looping through section as they  come around.

Comment: @WebElaine: that [array notation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) was introduced in PHP 5.4 in 2009.

Comment: I don't see any call to function my_plugin_builder() in ini.php, or are you calling from somewhere else? Also you would like to look into customize_register hook here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_section

Comment: @PiyushRawat I'm calling the my_plugin_builder() function in the init.php file, it's requiring the builder.php file where I have my dashboard code. The link you refered me to is for adding sections to the customizer. I'm trying to add a plugin options page here, not using the customizer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work, I removed the my_plugin_init_settings function and outputted its content directly and called do_settings_sections after it.